# What will be the time complexity of this function?

Tags: java, algorithm, analysis

This is the function to check the string of pattern a^nb^n.

Input : str = "aabb" Output : Yes

Input : str = "abab" Output : No

Input : str = "aabbb" Output : No

Can someone please help determine the time complexity?
As the loop will run n/2 times , is it still linear ?

```
 public static boolean isAnBn(String s)
    {
        int l = s.length();

        // Only even length strings will have same number of a's and b's
        if (l%2 == 1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        // Set two pointers, one from the left and another from right
        int i = 0;
        int j = l-1;

        // Compare the characters till the center
        while (i<j)
        {
            if(s.charAt(i) != 'a' || s.charAt(j) != 'b')
            {
                return false;
            }
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Yes. Your loop run time is linearly proportional to the length of the input - so `O(n)`.

Comment: Why can't you do this yourself?

Comment: I am still learning about analysis and time complexities . got confused where loop runs n/2 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will still be linear time. In the worse case, you'll have to go through each character if `i` is never equal to `'a'` or `j`  is never `'b'`. When it comes to big O think about the worse case. 
I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Complexity is `O(n)`.

Don't be confused about n/2. Constant values, 1/2 in your case, should be ignored.

For example:

- n/2 = O(n)
- 3n = O(n)
- 10000000n = O(n)
- etc..